# Unity3D MissingReferenceException when removing BoxCollider

Tags: c#, exception, unity-game-engine, editor, components

I'm developing an open source editor tool for Unity3D https://github.com/JAFS6/BoxStairsTool and I'm writting a CustomEditor.

I create a main GameObject and I attach my script *BoxStairs* to it. This script attachs to the same *GameObject* a *BoxCollider*.

On my *CustomEditor* code, I have a method which is in charge of removing both two components attached before to finalize editing.

This is the code:

```
    private void FinalizeStairs ()
    {
        Undo.SetCurrentGroupName("Finalize stairs");
        BoxStairs script = (BoxStairs)target;
        GameObject go = script.gameObject;
        BoxCollider bc = go.GetComponent<BoxCollider>();

        if (bc != null)
        {
            Undo.DestroyObjectImmediate(bc);
        }
        Undo.DestroyObjectImmediate(target);
    }
```

This method is called on the method *OnInspectorGUI* after a button has been pressed

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI ()
{
    ...
    if (GUILayout.Button("Finalize stairs"))
    {
        FinalizeStairs();
    }
}
```

Both two methods are on the class

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(BoxStairs))]
public sealed class BoxStairsEditor : Editor
```

It actually removes the two components but, once the *BoxCollider* has been removed the following error appears:

```
MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'BoxCollider' has been 
destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
```

I try to locate where the error is ocurring by looking at the trace:

```
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
UnityEditor.Editor.IsEnabled () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Inspector/Editor.cs:590)
UnityEditor.InspectorWindow.DrawEditor (UnityEditor.Editor editor, Int32 editorIndex, Boolean rebuildOptimizedGUIBlock, System.Boolean& showImportedObjectBarNext, UnityEngine.Rect& importedObjectBarRect) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Inspector/InspectorWindow.cs:1154)
UnityEditor.InspectorWindow.DrawEditors (UnityEditor.Editor[] editors) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Inspector/InspectorWindow.cs:1030)
UnityEditor.InspectorWindow.OnGUI () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Inspector/InspectorWindow.cs:352)
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:222)
```

But none of my scripts appears on it.

I've been looking on the code where I'm referencing the *BoxCollider* and the only place is where it is created, when the stairs are created which is triggered once a change has happened on the inspector.

It is in the class:

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
[SelectionBase]
public sealed class BoxStairs : MonoBehaviour
```

This is the code:

```
    /*
     * This method creates a disabled BoxCollider which marks the volume defined by
     * StairsWidth, StairsHeight, StairsDepth.
     */
    private void AddSelectionBox ()
    {
        BoxCollider VolumeBox = Root.GetComponent<BoxCollider>();

        if (VolumeBox == null)
        {
            VolumeBox = Root.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
        }

        if (Pivot == PivotType.Downstairs)
        {
            VolumeBox.center = new Vector3(0, StairsHeight * 0.5f, StairsDepth * 0.5f);
        }
        else
        {
            VolumeBox.center = new Vector3(0, -StairsHeight * 0.5f, -StairsDepth * 0.5f);
        }

        VolumeBox.size = new Vector3(StairsWidth, StairsHeight, StairsDepth);

        VolumeBox.enabled = false;
    }
```

I've tried to comment this method's body to allow removing the *BoxCollider* without this "reference" and the error still appears, so, I guess this method is not the problem.

Also, I've removed the *BoxCollider* manually, without clicking the Finalize button to trigger this code, via right click on the component on the inspector "Remove Component" option and the error not appears and after that, click over finalize stairs and no problem shows up.

As @JoeBlow mentioned in the comments I've checked that the **FinalizeStairs** method **is called just once**.

Also I've checked that the process of creation with the call to *AddSelectionBox* method it is not happening on the moment of clicking finalize button.

So, please I need a hand on this. This is the link to the development branch https://github.com/JAFS6/BoxStairsTool/tree/feature/BoxStairsTool, here you will find that the above mentioned method **FinalizeStairs** has the code wich removes the BoxStairs script only and on that moment it throws no errors.

Any idea or advice on this will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:

**Asset/BoxStairs.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BoxStairsTool
{
    [ExecuteInEditMode]
    [SelectionBase]
    public sealed class BoxStairs : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private GameObject Root;

        private void Start ()
        {
            Root = this.gameObject;
            this.AddSelectionBox();
        }

        private void AddSelectionBox()
        {
            BoxCollider VolumeBox = Root.GetComponent<BoxCollider>();

            if (VolumeBox == null)
            {
                VolumeBox = Root.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
            }

            VolumeBox.size = new Vector3(20, 20, 20);

            VolumeBox.enabled = false;
        }

    }
}
```

**Asset\Editor\BoxStairsEditor.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

namespace BoxStairsTool
{
    [CustomEditor(typeof(BoxStairs))]
    public sealed class BoxStairsEditor : Editor
    {
        private const string DefaultName = "BoxStairs";

        [MenuItem("GameObject/3D Object/BoxStairs")]
        private static void CreateBoxStairsGO ()
        {
            GameObject BoxStairs = new GameObject(DefaultName);
            BoxStairs.AddComponent<BoxStairs>();

            if (Selection.transforms.Length == 1)
            {
                BoxStairs.transform.SetParent(Selection.transforms[0]);
                BoxStairs.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0,0,0);
            }

            Selection.activeGameObject = BoxStairs;
            Undo.RegisterCreatedObjectUndo(BoxStairs, "Create BoxStairs");
        }

        public override void OnInspectorGUI ()
        {
            if (GUILayout.Button("Finalize stairs"))
            {
                FinalizeStairs();
            }
        }

        private void FinalizeStairs ()
        {
            Undo.SetCurrentGroupName("Finalize stairs");
            BoxStairs script = (BoxStairs)target;
            GameObject go = script.gameObject;
            BoxCollider bc = go.GetComponent<BoxCollider>();

            if (bc != null)
            {
                Undo.DestroyObjectImmediate(bc);
            }
            Undo.DestroyObjectImmediate(target);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: surely this FinalizeStairs is being called more than once, or something like that?  just add a trivial line of code Debug.Log("I am in FinalizeStairs " +gameObject.name); at the top of that routine.

Comment: I dont understand why you destroy the component if you then destroy "target" anyway?

Comment: I've added the Debug.Log @JoeBlow mentioned and the result is the same, the message shows just before the error.

Comment: @JoeBlow I thought using 'target' will destroy the GameObject but it doesn't, it removes the BoxStairs script component.

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue what "target" is; I find it hard to follow the code.  Perhaps click Edit and simply paste in the entire script(s)

Comment: target is not a variable of mine, it is from Unity, here is the reference https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor-target.html. If I show target.name, the name which shows up it is the GameObject's name, so I think target is a reference to the GameObject, but like you said, DestroyObjectImmediate(target) should destroy the GameObject, but it doesn't, it only removes the BoxStairs script.

Comment: try `if (bc != null && Event.current.type == EventType.Layout)` and also add an `else` statement afterwards

Comment: @Bijan It enters only on the else part

Comment: I've tried to delete the complete GameObject with `BoxStairs script = (BoxStairs)target;    GameObject go = script.gameObject;     Undo.DestroyObjectImmediate(go);` just to see what could happen. The GameObject is deleted completely but the MissingReferenceException still persists.

Comment: I forgot to ask does FinalizeStairs run in OnGUI()?

Comment: Maybe the engine is looking for the BoxCollider to perform some action? I have to point that the BoxCollider is not enabled due to I use it only to show a cubic volume.

Comment: @Bijan FinalizeStairs is called on the method **public override void OnInspectorGUI ()** after a button press `if (GUILayout.Button("Finalize stairs"))
            {
                FinalizeStairs();
            }`

Comment: Which version of unity are you using? I have been trying to use your github project in 5.4 and here it seems to function without any form of problems. No exception is thrown.

Comment: @MXD I'm using version 5.4 but, as you can notice the github code doesn't remove the BoxCollider, that's because I've not commited the code with errors, you are seeing the code prior to the changes proposed on this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Analysis

I'm a programmer, so I just debug to find the problem (in my mind :D).

> MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'BoxCollider' has been  destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
> Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
> UnityEditor.Editor.IsEnabled () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Inspector/Editor.cs:590)

A MissingReferenceException occurs when the code trys to access a Unity3D.Object after it has been destroyed.

Let's look into the decompiled code of `UnityEditor.Editor.IsEnabled()`.

```
internal virtual bool IsEnabled()
{
    UnityEngine.Object[] targets = this.targets;
    for (int i = 0; i < targets.Length; i++)
    {
        UnityEngine.Object @object = targets[i];
        if ((@object.hideFlags & HideFlags.NotEditable) != HideFlags.None)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (EditorUtility.IsPersistent(@object) && !AssetDatabase.IsOpenForEdit(@object))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

We won't be able to know which line is the specific line 590. But, we can tell where can a `MissingReferenceException` happen:

```
//    ↓↓↓↓↓↓
if ((@object.hideFlags & HideFlags.NotEditable) != HideFlags.None)
```

`@object` is assigned from [Editor.targets](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor-targets.html) which is *an array of all the object being inspected*. There should be only one target object in this array in your case - the `BoxCollider` component.

**In conclusion**, the inspector failed to access the target object (I mean `targets[0]`) after you calls `Undo.DestroyObjectImmediate` on the `BoxCollider` component.

If you dig into the decompiled code of the inspector(`UnityEditor.InspectorWindow`), you will see that the overridden `OnInspectorGUI` function is called per Editor **in order** in `UnityEditor.InspectorWindow.DrawEditors`, including the internal editor of BoxCollider and your custom editor `BoxStairsEditor` of `BoxStairs` .

## Solutions

1. Do not destory a component that is being shown by the Inspector in `OnInspectorGUI`.
   Maybe you can add a delegate instance to [EditorApplication.update](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorApplication-update.html) to do that instead. In this way, the deleting operation will not break the editor/inspector GUI of `BoxCollider`.
2. <s>Move the created component `BoxCollider` upper than your `BoxStairs` component before you destroy it. This may work but I'm not sure if other internal editor will access the `BoxCollider` or not.</s> This solution not works when using `UnityEditorInternal.ComponentUtility.MoveComponentUp`. But, if the user manually move up the `BoxCollider` component, it works without any code changes.

## Code of solution

After using solution 1, the NRE is gone on Unity3D 5.4 on Win10.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

namespace BoxStairsTool
{
    [CustomEditor(typeof(BoxStairs))]
    public sealed class BoxStairsEditor : Editor
    {
        private const string DefaultName = "BoxStairs";

        [MenuItem("GameObject/3D Object/BoxStairs")]
        private static void CreateBoxStairsGO ()
        {
            GameObject BoxStairs = new GameObject(DefaultName);
            BoxStairs.AddComponent<BoxStairs>();

            if (Selection.transforms.Length == 1)
            {
                BoxStairs.transform.SetParent(Selection.transforms[0]);
                BoxStairs.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0,0,0);
            }

            Selection.activeGameObject = BoxStairs;
            Undo.RegisterCreatedObjectUndo(BoxStairs, "Create BoxStairs");
        }

        private void OnEnable ()
        {
            EditorApplication.update -= Update;
            EditorApplication.update += Update;
        }

        public override void OnInspectorGUI ()
        {
            if (GUILayout.Button("Finalize stairs"))
            {
                needFinalize = true;
            }
        }

        private void FinalizeStairs ()
        {
            Undo.SetCurrentGroupName("Finalize stairs");
            BoxStairs script = (BoxStairs)target;
            GameObject go = script.gameObject;
            BoxCollider bc = go.GetComponent<BoxCollider>();

            if (bc != null)
            {
                Undo.DestroyObjectImmediate(bc);
            }
            Undo.DestroyObjectImmediate(target);
        }

        bool needFinalize;
        void Update()
        {
            if(needFinalize)
            {
                FinalizeStairs();
                needFinalize = false;
                EditorApplication.update -= Update;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tested the second option. I've moved the component before the script component prior to its destruction, the component is correctly moved but when it is destroyed the exceptions rises again. `UnityEditorInternal.ComponentUtility.MoveComponentUp(bc);

            if (bc != null)
            {
                Undo.DestroyObjectImmediate(bc);
            }`

Comment: I've tested the first option, Created a method to destroy BC `private void RemoveSelectionBox () { BoxStairs script = (BoxStairs)target; GameObject go = script.gameObject; BoxCollider bc = go.GetComponent<BoxCollider>(); if (bc != null) { Undo.DestroyObjectImmediate(bc); } }`   And I've added it to the EditorApplication.update this way `EditorApplication.update = RemoveSelectionBox;` on _FinalizeStairs_ method just before `Undo.DestroyObjectImmediate(target);` Now when pressing the finalize button, the error shows a lot of times and it doesn't stops, I need to reset Unity editor to stop it.

Comment: Remeber to **remove** the delegate instance from `EditorApplication.update` after you destroyed the `BoxCollider`

Comment: Maybe by setting `EditorApplication.update` to `null` after the destruction in the `RemoveSelectionBox`.

Comment: I've added `EditorApplication.update = null;`` at the end of **RemoveSelectionBox** method and nothing changed, the error keeps showing a lot of times.

Comment: I can't paste the full code due to character limitation, the full code can be seen here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JAFS6/BoxStairsTool/feature/BoxStairsTool/Assets/BoxStairsTool/BoxStairs.cs and https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JAFS6/BoxStairsTool/feature/BoxStairsTool/Assets/BoxStairsTool/Editor/BoxStairsEditor.cs. Obviously, the code found there is just previous to modification of **FinalizeStairs** method which can be found full at the top of this question. The error is the one I've described on the question.

Comment: Hi! I'm willing to help but I really don't have much time digging into the repo. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Unity3D project](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok, Minimal example. Get https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5252395/BoxStairsToolMinimal.zip, unzip on Assets folder on a fresh unity project, right click on Hierarchy, create 3D Object -> BoxStairs, then, on inspector click over finalize stairs button. Error will appear on console.

Comment: The answer is updated. Solution 1 does work in my environment.

Comment: It works! Thanks. I need to ask, if you add the delegate on _OnEnable_ method, it will be added once each time you select the root GameObject on the hierarchy, but only removed once when click over finalize button, this additions are not cumulative?

Comment: Oh, that is cumulative. We should call `EditorApplication.update -= Update` first. The answer is updated.

Comment: Why not add it to the OnDisable method or to an else part of `if (GUILayout.Button("Finalize stairs"))`?

Comment: I'm not sure. You may try that yourself.

Comment: I've done it, the effect seems the same on the 3 cases.